# How to make recycler view go to only next item onFling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I will not use `pagerSnapHelper` as I am getting some issues. I would like to add `onFling`  listener to recyclerView. Then I want to pass a small velocity just to go to next item, instead of actual fling velocity. Is this possible? What would be this `mMinFlingVelocity`?

Code:

```
 recyclerView.onFlingListener = object : OnFlingListener(){
        override fun onFling(velocityX: Int, velocityY: Int): Boolean {
            Log.d("Tag", "fling")
            recyclerView.fling(0, 1)
            return true
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this method to avoid `SnapHelper`

```
recyclerView.onFlingListener = object : RecyclerView.OnFlingListener(){
                override fun onFling(velocityX: Int, velocityY: Int): Boolean {
                    val minFlingVelocity = ViewConfiguration.get(recyclerView.context).scaledMinimumFlingVelocity
                    if (abs(velocityX) > minFlingVelocity) {
                        val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
                        val currentPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                        val nextPosition = if (velocityX > 0) currentPosition + 1 else currentPosition - 1

                        val itemCount = recyclerView.adapter?.itemCount ?: 0
                        if (nextPosition in 0 until itemCount) {
                            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(nextPosition)
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    return false
                }
            }
```

Here I'm doing :

1. Calculating the position of the next item based on the current scroll position and velocity
2. Check if the next position is within the range of the adapter
3. Scroll smoothly to the next position

Let me know if it works for you.

### Edit

Create a custom LinearSmoothScroller

```
class CustomLinearSmoothScroller(context: Context) : LinearSmoothScroller(context) {

    override fun calculateSpeedPerPixel(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics): Float {
        val minFlingVelocity = ViewConfiguration.get(context).scaledMinimumFlingVelocity
        return minFlingVelocity.toFloat() / displayMetrics.densityDpi
    }

}
```

And then add it in the `onFligListener`

```
recyclerView.onFlingListener = object : OnFlingListener(){
    override fun onFling(velocityX: Int, velocityY: Int): Boolean {
        val minFlingVelocity = ViewConfiguration.get(recyclerView.context).scaledMinimumFlingVelocity
        if (abs(velocityX) > minFlingVelocity) {
            val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
            val currentPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
            val nextPosition = if (velocityX > 0) currentPosition + 1 else currentPosition - 1

            val itemCount = recyclerView.adapter?.itemCount ?: 0
            if (nextPosition in 0 until itemCount) {
                val smoothScroller = CustomLinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.context)
                smoothScroller.targetPosition = nextPosition
                layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller)
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Maybe this is my appSpecific problem, but I can scroll to next item as expected but when I go to previous item, 2 or multiple items are scrolled back.

Comment: @Rifat have you tried my update?